# Placeholder not working on custom schema element

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am trying to get some value from a placeholder into a custom schema attribute (cfg:merge-elements' target) but it doesn't work:

**somexml.xml:**

```
<bean id="stateMachineNamingStrategy" class="com.mycompany.statemachine.hibernate.StateMachineNamingStrategy">
    <property name="prefix" value="${statemachine.table_prefix}"/>
</bean>

<cfg:merge-elements id="packages-com.mycompany.statemachine" target="${session-factory-pkgs}">
    <value>com.mycompany.statemachine.machine.impl</value>
</cfg:merge-elements>
```

Those definitions are in the same xml. The first one (stateMachineNamingStrategy) gets the value from ${statemachine.table_prefix} correctly.

The second isn't able to retrieve it in **${session-factory-pkgs}**. The exception shows that the attribute value hasn't been transformed:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${session-factory-pkgs}' is defined
```

Why doesn't it convert the placeholder to its value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem:

it turns out that in my `NamespaceHandler` I register a new BeanDefinition that extends `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. These special post processors are executed before normal `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to allow registration o deletion of BeanDefinitions. Thus, there's no way to make PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (which is a normal BeanPostProcessor) execute before the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.

You can see it all in XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors:

```
        Map<String, BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor> beanMap =
                beanFactory.getBeansOfType(BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.class, true, false);
        List<BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor> registryPostProcessorBeans =
                new ArrayList<BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor>(beanMap.values());
        OrderComparator.sort(registryPostProcessorBeans);
        for (BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor postProcessor : registryPostProcessorBeans) {

            //!!!!! BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors are excecuted!!!!!
            postProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(registry);
        }
        invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(registryPostProcessors, beanFactory);
        invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(registryPostProcessorBeans, beanFactory);
        invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(regularPostProcessors, beanFactory);
        processedBeans.addAll(beanMap.keySet());
    }
    else {
        // Invoke factory processors registered with the context instance.
        invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(getBeanFactoryPostProcessors(), beanFactory);
    }

    // Do not initialize FactoryBeans here: We need to leave all regular beans
    // uninitialized to let the bean factory post-processors apply to them!
    String[] postProcessorNames =
            beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(BeanFactoryPostProcessor.class, true, false);

    // Separate between BeanFactoryPostProcessors that implement PriorityOrdered,
    // Ordered, and the rest.
    List<BeanFactoryPostProcessor> priorityOrderedPostProcessors = new ArrayList<BeanFactoryPostProcessor>();
    List<String> orderedPostProcessorNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> nonOrderedPostProcessorNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String ppName : postProcessorNames) {
```